# Why is a label being cut off in cytoscape?

Tags: javascript, label, cytoscape.js

In cytoscape.js, I want to position a label at the top left corner of a parent node, with the text starting at the anchor point (i.e. left aligned with the text appearing to run across the top of the parent node).

I have set values for the text-halign, text-valign and text-justification:

```
'text-halign': 'left',
'text-justification': 'left',
'text-valign': 'top',
```

However, the text does not always appear. In this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tallrobot/x6k7dzq8/9/) the label does not initially appear - you only get a portion of the 'p':

[image: Parent node with label cut off]

However, if you zoom in on the top left corner of the parent node (using the mousewheel), the label does eventually appear in the correct place:

[image: parent label after zooming in]

I've also noticed that if I set the text-background properties for the parent node, these get drawn right aligned and not under the actual label:

[image: label background offset]

I've seen the same problem with child nodes too (though that is not shown in this example).

I have tried with various combinations of the `text-` properties. Although the label appears fully when zoomed in, it is always cut off at lower zoom levels.

Is there a way of getting the text to appear at the top left of the parent node and displayed in full without having to zoom in?

Comment: `'text-margin-y': 0,` did you tried changing this value ? Try giving a `-1`.

Comment: I tired that: the problem is still the same, just 1 pixel higher :-)

Comment: https://prnt.sc/KEDi0qxr-QUV   Check this screenshot, I got this when the margin is -1

Comment: Yes - that's the same problem as in my first screenshot, just 1 pixel higher. In both cases only part of the 'p' is being shown, not the whole label of 'parent'

Comment: Just to be clear: I want the label 'parent' to be shown above the grey box left aligned with the top left corner. When I set up the cytoscape styles to do that, the label is cut off unless I zoom in

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this library, so please excuse me if this didnt solve your issue.
After making some changes and looking into the documentation, I found that `'text-wrap':'wrap'` adding this property in the style will solve your issue.

Please take a look at the code snippet

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,

  style: [
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'background-color': 'gray',
        label: 'data(id)',
        'text-margin-y': 1,
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'node:parent',
      style: {
        'border-opacity': 0,
        'background-color': 'lightgray',
        'text-halign': 'left',
        'text-valign': 'top',
        'text-margin-x': 45,
        'text-justification': 'left',
        'text-wrap':'wrap'
      }
    }
    ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [
      { data: { id: 'parent' } },
      { data: { id: 'child1', parent: 'parent' }, position: { x: 300, y: 85 }},
      { data: { id: 'child2', parent: 'parent' }, position: { x: 400, y: 85 }},
      { data: { id: 'node' }, position: { x: 500, y: 85 }},
    ],
    edges: []
  },

  layout: {
    name: 'preset',
    padding: 5
  }
});
```

```css
#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.23.0/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Akhil. That does indeed put the label in the correct place. However, it looks to me like `text-wrap` only works there because `text-margin-x` is set to shift the label by exactly the right amount (45 in this case). That field only takes a pixel value (and not, for example, a percentage of of the label length), so if I have a lot of different nodes with labels of different length, they will all be drawn incorrectly unless they are 45 pixels in length.

Answer (score 0):

Using a specific private field you can easily get the node label width. I would always prefer to use a normal API method as it is normally not really intended to use these fields. As there is no method to get this data right now, this will get you the width:

```js
'text-margin-x': (ele) => ele._private.rscratch.labelWidth
```

This may result in some errors, so I added a case where the labelWidth is null:

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,

  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'background-color': 'gray',
        label: 'data(id)',
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'node:parent',
      style: {
        'border-opacity': 0,
        'background-color': 'lightgray',
        'text-halign': 'left',
        'text-valign': 'top',
        'text-margin-x': (ele) => ele._private.rscratch.labelWidth ? ele._private.rscratch.labelWidth : 0
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'parent'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'child1',
          parent: 'parent'
        },
        position: {
          x: 300,
          y: 85
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'child2',
          parent: 'parent'
        },
        position: {
          x: 400,
          y: 85
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'node'
        },
        position: {
          x: 500,
          y: 85
        }
      },
    ],
    edges: []
  },

  layout: {
    name: 'preset',
    padding: 5
  }
});
```

```css
#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.23.0/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks, Stephan. I agree with you - I'd rather use a normal API but that private property works. FWIW I think there is some issue with how the label position is being calculated, specifically around some caching of the elements. I haven't followed the flow all the way through the code yet, but I found if I forced it to always redraw the text rather than use the element in ElementTextureCache, the label appeared.